# How to fit vector fields in Python?

Tags: python, vector

I have looked around a bit but not found a simple answer to my current Problem.

Given data on an irregular grid of a 2d vector field (every point in the x,y plane has a associated 2d vector p), is there an easy/convenient way in Python to fit a Matrix A to my data, so that p = A*(x,y) (sorry not sure how to create proper vector notation here).

I hope my question is clear... Please let me know if I overlooked a similar question or a straight forward resource.

Cheers
Christian

Comment: Could you give an example output?

Comment: In A*(x,y), what would x,y be ? Did you consider using numpy ?

Comment: This simple inquiry got me to think some more and I now realise that my question does not make sense in the context of my problem. What I actualy want is to fit some sort of position dependend polynomial to the each of the two components of (what I called) the vector p. Thus I deal with fitting two scalar valued 2d functions for which multiple resources are availabel on how to do this. Sorry for wasting everyones time!